# What do the various columns in schema_version_history table of flyway represent?

Tags: postgresql, flyway, dbmigrate

I'm new to flyway & have been going through the documentation of flyway but couldn't find a doc which describes what each column in schema_version_history (or whatever you would have configured to name the flyway table) means. I'm specifically intrigued by the column named "type". So far the possible values for this column that I've observed in some legacy project at work are SQL & DELETE.

But I have no clue what this means in terms of flyway migrations.

Below are some sample rows from the table. Note that for installed rank 54 & 56, same migration file is present with same checksum but one has type SQL and another has DELETE.

```
-[ RECORD 53 ]-+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
installed_rank | 54
version        | 2022.11.18.11.35.49.65
description    | add column seqence in attribute table
type           | SQL
script         | V2022_11_18_11_35_49_65__add_column_seqence_in_attribute_table.sql
checksum       | 408921517
installed_by   | postgres
installed_on   | 2022-11-18 12:04:47.652058
execution_time | 345
success        | t

-[ RECORD 54 ]-+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
installed_rank | 55
version        | 2022.11.15.14.17.44.36
description    | update address column in attribute table
type           | DELETE
script         | V2022_11_15_14_17_44_36__update_address_column_in_attribute_table.sql
checksum       | 1347853326
installed_by   | postgres
installed_on   | 2022-11-18 14:52:09.265902
execution_time | 0
success        | t
-[ RECORD 55 ]-+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
installed_rank | 56
version        | 2022.11.18.11.35.49.65
description    | add column seqence in attribute table
type           | DELETE
script         | V2022_11_18_11_35_49_65__add_column_seqence_in_attribute_table.sql
checksum       | 408921517
installed_by   | postgres
installed_on   | 2022-11-18 14:52:09.265902
execution_time | 0
success        | t
-[ RECORD 56 ]-+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
installed_rank | 58
version        | 2022.11.18.11.35.49.65
description    | add column seqence in attribute table
type           | SQL
script         | V2022_11_18_11_35_49_65__add_column_seqence_in_attribute_table.sql
checksum       | 408921517
installed_by   | postgres
installed_on   | 2022-12-09 14:01:59.352589
execution_time | 174
success        | t
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question. This is as close as I got to documentation on that table:

https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/exploring-the-flyway-schema-history-table

That article doesn't really describe the type column well at all, suggesting it only has two possible values and I've seen at least three; DELETE, SQL and JDBC. Not sure what else it may have.

EDIT: Also now confirmed these two values; BASELINE and UNDO_SQL

It's actually marked as intentionally not documented since it's not a part of the public API:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/faq#case-sensitive